# Records for past 24 hours oracle with start date and end date

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I find records in past 24 hours in oracle in a table with start date and end date. Both start date and end date should be in past 24 hours. Which one is right from the below

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE START_date <= SYSDATE -1 
AND STOP_date >= SYSDATE -1
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE START_date >= SYSDATE -1 
AND STOP_date <= SYSDATE -1
```

Comment: First query: the range contains the second `sysdate - 1`. Second query: the range *is* the second `sysdate - 1` :-) Both are obviously not what you are after.

Answer (score 3):

It would have started after yesterday, same time, and ended until now:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE START_date > SYSDATE - 1 
AND STOP_date <= SYSDATE;
```